# Elasticsearch Sorting in rails(On the basis of email)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

Am using gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.1.6'. When am trying to sort on the basis of email(string) e.g sajjad@yahoo.com, it divided in multiple part. As a result sorting result in not correct.
Any idea?

Comment: i solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, and this is working for me.

```
settings do
  mapping dynamic: false do
    [:sort_name, :email, :status].each do |attr|
      indexes attr, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed
    end

    [:name].each do |attr|
      indexes attr, type: 'string'
    end
 end
end
```